# Quality of rendering shadow in transparent png on Android

Tags: android, png

When using a transparent PNG image which has a fine fading shadow always there is an edge line around the shadow on the Android screen. It does not show this in emualator or Exclipse. See photo.

I wonder if there is way to improve on this. Is this something to do with inability of Android screen to show all 24 bit colours or the fact that is scaling and resampling image?

In this example the image is loaded into an ImageButton view. I tried it as source or background and it is the same quality.

[image]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The artefact you are seeing is known as "banding" and it is a consequence of your display being 16bits per pixel.

The best way to resolve this is to add some "noise" to your image asset in Photoshop or Paint.NET.

Alternatively you can set your window to be 32bpp with the following line added to your activity's `onCreate()`, between `super.onCreate()` and `setContentView()`. :

```
    getWindow().setFormat(PixelFormat.RGBA_8888);
```

Comment: Thank you. getWindow().setFormat(PixelFormat.RGBA_8888); does work! Not sure what do you mean about adding "noise" in Photoshop? The image/button above is using blur as the shadow effect.

Comment: @Reuben: Interesting, didn't know this trick. I've had the issues with banding, are there any specific downsides to using this `setFormat` method?

Comment: The downside is that your window requires twice as much RAM, and rendering may be slower (particularly software rendering) as a result of twice as much memory being accessed.

Comment: The frame rate drops from 60 to 38 when using 8888 and scrolling background on my HTC desire HD, but it works well for static screens and buttons.

Comment: As predicted two comments up. :-)  Btw, it's worth noting that Google have quietly made 8888 the default format (from Honeycomb onwards IIRC).

Comment: @ReubenScratton Good answer. But can you please add bit more information about this part - *The best way to resolve this is to add some "noise" to your image asset in Photoshop or Paint.NET*

Comment: By "noise" I refer to the effect of that name found in bitmap graphics packages like Photoshop, Gimp, etc. Adding 'noise' to an image is to add random speckling which, in this case, serves to break up the unwanted banding effect that you often get with pure gradients on 16bpp displays.