# Android transparent png shadow rendering poorly

Tags: android, graphics, mobile, png

I am testing a mobile site at the moment on android and have noticed that all my transparent images that have a shadow at the bottom are all rendering extremely poorly. I have tried adding noise>0.5>uniform>monochromatic to the image to solve this but this hasnt helped at all i also tried adding noise>2.0>gausiann>monochromatic but again got no change.

its clear that the image is being rendered as png8 even though im saving out the image as png24. i am also using the most up to date version of the android browser 2.3.3

Can anyone shine any light on this problem?

Comment: If this is happening on a real device (and not on the emulator, this might be a mobile provider compressing/color-reducing images before sending it over the air to "speed up" mobile data.

Comment: hi Phillip yeah this is happening on a real device, testing on htc desire hd

Answer (score 0):

I know its old but the solution is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4680987/969325).
To summarize: Use following code in onCreate(), between super.onCreate() and setContentView() in your activity:

```
getWindow().setFormat(PixelFormat.RGBA_8888);
```